# FullCalendar current week on top

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

Trying to see if theres a way to get the current week on top with Fullcalendar. I can see if you push it to 6 weeks the next months 1st week is just added to the bottom, so it would seem its possible to have the current week on top, and the remaining weeks below. Is there some kind of switch or parameter im missing for this?

Im currently using a fork that was made to import multiple .ics files. Core source appears to be unmolested. https://gitlab.nomagic.uk/popi/js_calendar_from_ics

Example:
[image]

Comment: FYI you don't need https://gitlab.nomagic.uk/popi/js_calendar_from_ics, fullCalendar already has its own functionality for this: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/icalendar

Comment: As for your actual question, I'm really not sure what you are trying to describe. Maybe a picture of your current calendar, and a mockup of what you're trying achieve, would be helpful. A picture can say 1000 words! Are you talking about the "dayGridMonth" view? If so then no, it always displays from the beginning of the current month, there is no option to change that. Available options are documented at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/month-view

Comment: I think what you're asking - if I understood it correctly! - would probably a require a completely [custom view](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/custom-view-with-js)

Comment: Sorry about the delay! Our baby came 3 weeks early, surprise! Added an example from Outlook to the original post.

As for not using the fork. I could not for the life of me get the standard deployment to work. Thats the only one that was functional with ics files

Comment: Thanks (and congratualations!). I see what you mean. Unfortunately no there is no option for this available in fullCalendar at the moment. You'd have to request it as a feature, or try to make a custom view of your own.